# How to store and access user-uploaded files inside a Nuxt 3 app

Tags: configuration, upload, nuxt.js

I am looking for a way to make an uploads folder in a Nuxt 3 app. The problem is, all the folders seem to be static. After uploading files to a folder, they become acceesible only after I build the project. Is there a configuration to make a folder inside the app that's handling data dynamically. What would be the correct way to arrange uploads like that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I found that the easiest way to do this is to actually serve the files via the API.

You still upload the files to the public directory but serve them from the API.
(PS: edit permissions to allow read and write on Linux, if on a server, do that via a docker container command)

Here is some code:

```
export function writeFileToStorage(given_path: string, locationsOnDisk: string[], file:any) {
    // TODO: Find a better way of serving static files in nuxt3 instead of using public folder
    // let root = `${path.join(process.cwd(), "public")}/uploads/${given_path}`
    let root = `${path.join(process.cwd(), "public", "uploads", given_path)}`
    let loc_url = `api/download/${given_path}`

    if (!fs.existsSync(root)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(root, {recursive: true})
    }

    let fullyQualifiedUrl = `${loc_url}/${file.originalFilename.replace(/ /g, "_")}`
    let fullyQualifiedPath = `${root}/${file.originalFilename.replace(/ /g, "_")}`

    // TODO: Find a better way of handling file name collisions, like fs.promises.access
    if (fs.existsSync(fullyQualifiedUrl)) {
        let fileName = file.originalFilename.split(".")
        let fileExtension = fileName.pop()
        let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.join(".")
        let counter = 1

        while (fs.existsSync(`${root}/${fileNameWithoutExtension}_${counter}.${fileExtension}`)) {
            counter++
        }

        fullyQualifiedUrl = `${loc_url}/${fileNameWithoutExtension}_${counter}.${fileExtension}`
        fullyQualifiedPath = `${root}/${fileNameWithoutExtension}_${counter}.${fileExtension}`
    }

    locationsOnDisk.push(fullyQualifiedUrl)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.rename(file.filepath, fullyQualifiedPath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(true)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```
export function readFilesFromStorage(user_id:string, chat_id:string, filename:string){
    const constructed_path = path.join(process.cwd(), "public", "uploads", user_id, chat_id, filename)
    try{
        return fs.readFileSync(constructed_path);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
export async function getFiles(event: H3Event) {
    const {user_id, chat_id, filename} = event.context.params || {};

    if (!user_id || !chat_id || !filename) {
        return null
    }

    return readFilesFromStorage(user_id, chat_id, filename);
}
```

And the full project at https://github.com/kgarchie/Ticketer